# Using a new stack to add existing service to existing load balancer

Tags: typescript, aws-cdk

I have:

- a stack that defines a cluster with an application load balancer and its listeners
- stacks that define ECS services.

I want to introduce a new stack that imports a listener and some services, and adds a listener rule which weight-forwards to some of the services, but I'm facing some limitations that I don't know how to circumvent.

First, I cannot add the imported service as a target group target. Importing the service gives me an `IEc2Service`, but application target groups require more specific types for services.

Second, I cannot add weighted targets to the listener. Importing a listener gives me an `IApplicationListener` which has the methods `addTargets` and `addTargetGroups`, but not the method `addAction`, which seems the only way to specify a `weightedForward` action.

Is there any way to solve that?

Comment: Are the stacks in the same CDK app?

Comment: That's too bad. [The read-only ISomething constructs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/resources.html#resources_importing) you get from the "import" methods are mainly glorified methods to pass around resource names and ARNs.  Combining the stacks in a single CDK app is the easiest solution.  If that's not possible, you should be able to wire things up manually with [L1 CfnSomething](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/constructs.html#constructs_l1_using) constructs.

Comment: Also see the [cross-stack-load-balancer](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-cdk-examples/tree/master/typescript/ecs/cross-stack-load-balancer) example in `aws-cdk-samples`.